# MySQL substring search in TEXT column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, substring

I have a column in an SQL table populated with the contents of an entire text file. Is there a way to get all substring matches of a particular term? For example, I want to get all occurrences of the words "bright star" starting 10 characters before the first occurrence and ending 10 characters after.

I was trying things like this with no success:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (PARAGRAPH, -10, 10) 
WHERE MATCH (paragraph) AGAINST ("+bright +star" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I know that MySQL queries can be deeply nested, but I don't know if it's even possible to perform such a search.

Many thanks,
A.

Comment: `+bright +star` will not only match `"bright star"` but `"bright"`, `"star"` and `"bright star"`.. add in table structure, example data (on sqlfiddle.com or db-fiddle.com) and add in expected results..

Comment: 10 characters before the first occurrence of what?

Comment: Full-text search doesn't return the position of the match, it just returns a score that indicates how well the search terms match the paragraph.

Comment: You can use the `LOCATE` function to find the position of a word in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-substr) to filter out subtring matches by your pattern.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(paragraph, '.{10}[bright|star].{10}')
```

Comment: Regexp came before in 5.4, but to use this specific function you need version 8

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking. Before 8.0 all you have is regexp matching, not regexp functions.

Comment: @EricAmshukov Experimented a little. It works perfectly. Thank you and everyone for your help. BTW, one of the arguments passed is occurrences. By default, mySQL will give the first match. I checked the documentation, I couldn't find an option to set a global flag or to get all occurrences of the pattern. Has anyone any experience with this?